# Non Existent Volume Keeps Showing Up in Files and in Favorites Bar

Tags: mount, files, filesystem, unmount

Just installed Ubuntu for the first time this morning, for some reason I see a drive called "64 GB Volume" that I am unable to open or unmount. When attempting to open it I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzoA0.png) error, and when attempting to unmount the drive by clicking the eject button nothing happens at all, it does dissapear from the favorites bar at this point, but it will reappear there on a reboot and stays in the Files application.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Edit: Just wanted to give an update and let everyone know that I am an idiot and I forgot that my laptop has an SD card drive, this is my work laptop and my boss had left an SD card in the slot. *facepalm*

Comment: Please add output of `sudo parted -l` command to the question.

Comment: This strange partition has been showing up recently.  Has something to do with updates and disappears on next update.  Would forget about it, since it is small and does not do anything except bug us. Think it is 64MB instead GB, big difference.

Comment: guessing from the length of the uuid it is the efi partition